Counterexamples to Goldbach's Conjecture in intervals $[N!+2,N!+N]$
Let me start by paraphrasing Richard Nixon by saying "I am not a crank!"; I am not "working on" Goldbach's Conjecture, this is an idle curiosity along similar lines to this question.
So, as any crank knows, you look at $2m$, and then you start looking at $2m-p$ for primes $p$. Well how about we place $2m$ in an interval where for about  $k\approx N/\ln N$ the first $k$ of the $2m-p$ (i.e. $2m-3,\,2m-5,\,2m-7,\dots,\,2m-p_k$) are all composite.
We can do this readily by considering $2m$ in the interval $[N!+2,N!+N]$, say $2m\approx N!+N$.
So some focused questions. The first a cursory Google could not answer for me; the second I doubt Google could answer.

Has anyone seriously looked for counterexamples in such an interval? If not, why not?

I understand that, using this notation, all such intervals up $N=20$ have been accounted for via verification up to $\approx 5\times 10^{18}$.

For standard numbers (without your filter on specific ranges), for even numbers $n$ in range $(10^{10}, 10^{11})$ for example, the number of couples $(p,q)$ of prime numbers such that $p+q=n$ is big, greater than $1000$ (I don't remember the estimation... but it is big). And there are simple formulas that give very good estimations of this number of couples. If you focus in range $(N!,  N!+N)$, you know that we are safe with prime numbers lower than $N$, (less than $10$ primes numbers in our range), but it still remains many thousands of couples $p,q$ such that $p+q=n$

@Lourrran I get you - while it may be true that many small primes exhibit Goldbach, throwing these out doesn't do anything because in general small primes aren't necessary. I think that answers the question (if not, why not?) if you would like to make your comment an answer.

Goldbach's conjecture is very 'weak'. It says that for any even number $n$ there exists at least one couple $(p,q)$ of prime numbers, such that $p+q=n$.
I say it is very weak because as far as we can check, we can see that there exist a very big number of couples $(p,q)$ such that $p+q=n$.
We can run small calculs.
For big numbers $n$, in range $(2, n)$, the number of prime numbers can be estimate by $\pi(n)=\frac{n}{ln(n)}$ ; when we combine all couples from this set, we obtain $\frac{\pi(n)^2}{2}$ couples. For all these couples, the sum $p+q$ is less than $2n$.
We have  $\frac{\pi(n)^2}{2}$ couples, that are 'dispached' in less than $n$ boxes.
This dispatching is not uniform, but we have in average $\frac{n}{ln(n)^2}$ couples in each box.
For numbers $r$ like $10^{20}$, this rough estimation says that we should have around $2 \times 10^{16}$ couples $(p,q)$ that give $p+q=r$.
If by any process, for some specific $r$, we can reduce this estimation by $10$, or $20$, it remains many many couples.
